# Action Center cannot switch on Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I can't seem to switch on my Windows Firewall no matter what!

List of things that I have tried and hasn't worked for me->

Disabled Avast Antivirus(free) and tried switching on
Went to services.msc> Windows Firewall> Start firewall
Scanned my computer with Malware bytes and Avast full scan and didn't find any virus/malwares.
Went to various Microsoft support threads and downloaded the Fix it tools like this one for example: [Microsoft Fixit tools](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2271812)

Comment: Are you the Admin for the system? Does it do this with all profiles or can you create a new one and have it work?

Comment: @Piyush Do you see any red exclamation points in the event log of Windows (`eventvwr.msc`)? These could give you some more information as to why the service won't turn on.

Comment: Yes Aaron I am the admin of the system.
@Rik : Yes there is a red exclamation in the event log. This is the log "The Windows Firewall service terminated with service-specific error The data is invalid.." 
As you can see the log is unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

> Yes there is a red exclamation in the event log. This is the log "The
>   Windows Firewall service terminated with service-specific error The
>   data is invalid.." As you can see the log is unhelpful.

Actually, the event log is very helpful. It tells us your firewall data became corrupted.

From [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/windows-firewall-service-will-not-start/986ccc05-24c2-498c-97c4-1378f7deef24)
and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/my-network-firewall-has-been-deactivated-of-some/d4b30715-31bc-45d6-97d7-da92ad735a27).

You didn't specify the exact EventID but you could try resetting the firewall with the following:

- Open a administrator prompt.
  (Click <kbd>Start</kbd>, type `cmd`, right-click `cmd.exe` and choose `Run as administrator`.)
- Copy and paste the following command (and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

`Rundll32 setupapi,InstallHinfSection Ndi-Steelhead 132 %windir%\inf\netrass.inf`

- Run the following command:
  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- See if you can start the service (or if it is already started).

If that doesn't work there is also the option (found in that [second link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/my-network-firewall-has-been-deactivated-of-some/d4b30715-31bc-45d6-97d7-da92ad735a27)) of running the "services repair tool by ESET" from [here](http://kb.eset.com/library/ESET/KB%20Team%20Only/Malware/ServicesRepair.exe).

If both methods don't work please provide the exact EventId and text (like in [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/windows-firewall-service-will-not-start/986ccc05-24c2-498c-97c4-1378f7deef24) topic) so we can search more precise for a solution.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much. The Eset services repair tool did it for me. Thanks a ton.

For the curious ones out there, the first step ( the one involving the cmd) threw this error "An error occured while trying to contact your Windows Firewall services.Make sure that your service is running and try again"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that would prevent windows firewall would be another instance of a firewall, from your already-installed anti-virus suite or similar.

You should try turning off the Avast firewall.

Comment: Does Avast Antivirus(free) come with a firewall? I don't think the free edition comes with a firewall.

Comment: Avast Antivirus ( free) does not come with a firewall. I don't have any other firewalls running on the system.